how to inject js to chrome extension pages? eg. to url like chrome-extension://[xxx]/json.html
I am developing an chrome extension, and i need to inject js to an iframe in extension pages. I have already set manifest host_permission to <all_urls>, but it won't work.
enter image description here
when i try to inject js to extension page, there is an error occurs:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
enter image description here
